# I am working on jmeter for one of my project which was developed based on java script and in that unable to find the boundaries of dynamic values

Tags: performance, jmeter, scripting

Hi i am working on project which was developed based on javasctipt. I have recorded the script and identified the dynic values but unable to find the boundaries of those dynamic values in previous requests and getting the boundaries in the same page request not in previous request. Due to this script is failing and i am unable to proceed further. Please some one suggest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) requires zero knowledge but it's not the best option when it comes to dealing with HTML responses.

The best one I think is [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor), however it's hard to tell anything without seeing the response you're getting (at least partial) and knowing what parts of it you want to extract.

See [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for example queries